# Matrix complex conjugate in OpenCV C++

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix

Does OpenCV provide any function to perform a matrix complex conjugate ?

The only function I've found which might in a way do this, is the `void mulSpectrums(InputArray a, InputArray b, OutputArray c, int flags, bool conjB=false)` function.

This is what the last argument does according to the doc:

> When the arrays are complex, they are simply multiplied (per element)
>   with an optional conjugation of the second-array elements

Isn't there a proper way of doing this for just one matrix, instead of having to multiply it, let's say, with an all-one matrix with the above function ?

I'm trying to do a complex conjugate on a matrix on which I applied a DFT.

Answer (score 1):

```
Mat OnesArr = Mat::ones(YourArr.width, YourArr.height, CV_32F);

mulSpectrums(OnesArr, YourArr, OutputArr, int flags, True);
```

conjugate(A) = I * conjugate(A) = mulSpectrum(I, A, , conj= true)

Comment: Although this code might (or might not) solve the problem, a good answer should also explain **what** the problem is and **how** the code helps.

Comment: I had already explained that. But auto editors are suggest to delete that text.

Comment: I guess with "auto editors" you mean the person who edited your question? "Like This:" and "Hope it helps" are no explanations of your code.

Comment: OK, I have added explanations to my answer.